# Pandas/Python - equalizing different indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes.

df1:

```
                     0            1            2
Date                                                                          
2005-10-01   772.142457  5600.491978 -5522.102692  
2005-11-01   445.861074  4866.226303 -4455.554864
2005-12-01  -390.237513   923.679907   379.381452
2006-01-01  -755.725402   673.734737   198.968080
2006-02-01  -755.725402   673.734737   198.968080
```

df2:

```
              Value
Date
2005-07-01 -0.07920
2005-08-01 -0.01412
2005-09-01 -0.03646
2005-10-01  0.17432
2005-11-01 -0.05409
2005-12-01  0.04988
2006-01-01 -0.00232
```

I want them to have the same indexes, so that df1 stays like this:

```
                     0            1            2
Date                                                                          
2005-07-01          NaN          NaN          NaN
2005-08-01          NaN          NaN          NaN
2005-09-01          NaN          NaN          NaN
2005-10-01   772.142457  5600.491978 -5522.102692  
2005-11-01   445.861074  4866.226303 -4455.554864
2005-12-01  -390.237513   923.679907   379.381452
2006-01-01  -755.725402   673.734737   198.968080
2006-02-01  -755.725402   673.734737   198.968080
```

And df2 stays like this:

```
              Value
Date
2005-07-01 -0.07920
2005-08-01 -0.01412
2005-09-01 -0.03646
2005-10-01  0.17432
2005-11-01 -0.05409
2005-12-01  0.04988
2006-01-01 -0.00232
2006-02-01      NaN
```

I've been searching for a while to get this done but I couldn't find any function for that :(

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

You want to [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) and pass the other df's `union`ed index as the new index to reindex against:

```
In [135]:
df.reindex(df1.index.union(df.index))

Out[135]:
                     0            1            2
Date                                            
2005-07-01         NaN          NaN          NaN
2005-08-01         NaN          NaN          NaN
2005-09-01         NaN          NaN          NaN
2005-10-01  772.142457  5600.491978 -5522.102692
2005-11-01  445.861074  4866.226303 -4455.554864
2005-12-01 -390.237513   923.679907   379.381452
2006-01-01 -755.725402   673.734737   198.968080
2006-02-01 -755.725402   673.734737   198.968080

In [134]:
df1.reindex(df.index.union(df1.index))
Out[134]:
              Value
Date               
2005-07-01 -0.07920
2005-08-01 -0.01412
2005-09-01 -0.03646
2005-10-01  0.17432
2005-11-01 -0.05409
2005-12-01  0.04988
2006-01-01 -0.00232
2006-02-01      NaN
```

You can create the combined index first and pass this to the above to make it more readable:

```
In [136]:
combined_idx = df.index.union(df1.index)
combined_idx

Out[136]:
DatetimeIndex(['2005-07-01', '2005-08-01', '2005-09-01', '2005-10-01',
               '2005-11-01', '2005-12-01', '2006-01-01', '2006-02-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

So  `df.reindex(combined_idx)` and `df1.reindex(combined_idx)` will work